# how to apply a function on columns of a numpy array using a conditional array?

Tags: python, numpy

```
arr = np. array([[ 1.        ,  9.98672295,  1.        ],
                 [ 2.        , 19.97344589,  2.        ],
                 [ 3.        , 29.96016884,  3.        ]])    
cnd = [True, False, True]    
func = lambda a : a.astype(int)
```

How can I apply the **func** only on the columns of **arr** which correspond to the **cnd** array as True (the first and the third one)?

The ideal outcome is:

```
outcome = np. array([[ 1        ,  9.98672295,  1        ],
                     [ 2        , 19.97344589,  2        ],
                     [ 3        , 29.96016884,  3        ]])
```

where the first and third columns are integers

Comment: Unless you convert it into structured numpy array, you cannot have mixed int and float array. Is this a sample example of a different function you are trying to apply on an array?

Comment: yes that would work also.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use

```
>>> arr[:, cnd].astype(int)
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 3]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it:

```
f2 = lambda a, i: func(a) if cnd[i] else a
f3 = lambda a: np.array([f2(row, i) for (i, row) in enumerate(a.T)]).T
```

I applied multiple functions to make it more readable, although arguably you can do it using a single function.

My only worry is that numpy would probably need to get the column types explicitly or it might coerce them all into the same type.